# How to keep display off?

Tags: c++, winapi, display, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to write a program in C++Builder 10.2 that turns off the display (by hotkey) via `SendMessage(handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);` I need the display to remain turned off while other keys are being typed, and then turn it back on by another hotkey. Is this possible?

Comment: See if [`SetThreadExecutionState(ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) does what you need. Though I suspect keyboard input will just "wake up" the computer again.  If this doesn't work, I don't know of any other options.  You might have to resort to communicating with the monitor hardware directly

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: `SetThreadExecutionState(ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED)` doesn't work, but I will try with other flags. My laptop doesn't have any "instant turn off display" function. I need the display to remain turned off while I listen to music (it saves battery charge and doesn't distract me)

Comment: @Avtem "*I need the display to remain turned off while I listen to music*" - what does that have to do with typing while the display is off? Are you using key presses to control the music playback?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not mention this. I use keyboard for control the music playback. I found this function [`DevicePowerSetDeviceState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/PowrProf/nf-powrprof-devicepowersetdevicestate) , but I did not find out how to call first parameter (I found one article, but I am still working on translating)

Comment: I guess you could create a TOPMOST window to cover the entire screen and fill it with black?

Comment: You mean do not turn off display at all? No, this is not what I'm trying to make